# Three questions about $E[X \mid Y,g(Y)] = E[X|Y]$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

**QUESTION 1**

$$\text{Show:} \quad E[X \mid Y,g(Y)] = E[X|Y]$$

My attempt:

To show this first I will condition on the event $Y=y$ and then at the end replace $y$ with $Y$...

$$E[X \mid Y=y,g(Y=y)] = \sum_x x P(X=x \mid Y=y, g(Y=y))$$

And the trick is to note that the two events $(Y=y) \cap (g(Y=y))$ is redundant and equal to just the event that $Y=y$, thus

$$= \sum_x x P(X=x \mid Y=y)$$

which looks familiar in its way to $E[X|Y]$ which completes the proof. Is this correct?

**QUESTION 2**

Following the same reasoning, since $E[X|Y]$ and $Var(X|Y)$ are just functions of $Y$, can you confirm the following are true:

$$E[X \mid Y,E[X|Y], Var(X|Y)] = E[X|Y]$$

**QUESTION 3**

I also believe

$$E[X \mid g(Y)] = E[X \mid Y]$$

is not always true... because given you know $g(Y) = k$ is different from knowing that $Y=y$, is that correct? Thank you.

Comment: For Q 3): let $X=Y$, $X$ taking values $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$ each and $g(y)=y^{2}$. Then $E(X|g(Y))=0$ and $E(X|Y)=X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your help! Hmmm based on your example, $g(Y)$ becomes a constant random variable equal to $1$, and it seems like you're saying $E[X|1] = 0$, is that correct? Maybe in general $E[X|c]$ is the constant RV $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Very interesting that is a good example... I didn't know that $E[X|c] = 0$, can you also comment on the other two questions? I appreciate your help. If you were to put it in even a brief answer I would be happy to accept it. I know my question isn't the most scintillating on this site but I sincerely appreciate the effort

Comment: FYI $$E[X|c] = E[X]$$ which you can see from question 2908945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 2) are correct. For 3) let $X$ take values $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 1 2 $ each, $Y=X$ and $g(y)=y^{2}$. In this case $E(X|g(Y))=0$ and $E(X|Y)=X$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know my questions are somewhat redundant but they give me better understanding. I did not know before that $E[X|c] = 0$, it doesn't make much sense to me... for example, $$E[X|c] = \frac{E[X \mathbf{1}_c]}{P(c)}$$ and I'm not sure what to even make of $P(c)$... let me know if this is another question or if it's just by definition or something that $E[X|c] = 0$, Thanks! =)